# loadRequest UIWebView from Different Class

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiwebview

I have 2 classes, `MainViewController` of kind UIViewController & `Foo` of kind UIView.

In `MainViewController` I implemented an `UIWebView` called `myWebView` and set it's delegate to self (MainViewController).

I'm trying to `loadRequest` this `UIWebView` from `Foo` class.

I would like to get some help, I created an instance variable of `MainViewController` and tried to `loadRequest` `myWebView` but with no success.

Thanks,

Comment: how did you add Foo ? by pushNavigation or addSubview ?

Comment: and do you want to loadRequest from MainViewController and display on Foo ?

Comment: I have 2 options, one is to call a method inside MainViewController from Foo that should loadRequest the UIWebView

-----------------
Option 2 is to loadRequest from Foo to affect an UIWebView inside MainViewController



Otherwise the UIWebView is inside MainViewController

Comment: Do you need to send the request from MVC to Foo?

Comment: Or to call a method inside MainViewController via Foo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get the instance of your mainviewcontroller which is already displayed on the screen and then call the request. You should not create a new instance as it would result in a new object.

Try having the references to all your viewcontrollers in the application delegate and pass them around.